# Installation of ddosim

Tags: libraries, system-administration

I have a problem when I want execute following ddosim :

```
root@localhost:~/ddosim-0.2#./ddosim

./ddosim: error while loading shared libraries: libpcap.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can tell me how to fix this please ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error message contains all the information you need. There is an unmet dependency.

Answer (score 2):

also don't forgot the following libnet0(dev) for your dependencies(for x64):

```
  131  wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/1315573/libnet0-dev_1.0.2a-7_amd64.deb
  134  wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/1315572/libnet0_1.0.2a-7_amd64.deb
  135  dpkg -i libnet0_1.0.2a-7_amd64.deb
  136  dpkg -i libnet0-dev_1.0.2a-7_amd64.deb
```

Did you get it work eventually?

Answer (score -1):

enter the command promt and have 
apt-get install libcap-dev